# Добавить элемент рядом

Tags: jquery

Допустим есть где-то блок с классом "asd" и рядом с ним нужно добавить DOM, что-то наподобие .append\.prepend, только не **в**, а рядом.

Есть такое решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.asd').after('<div class="new">new</div>');
});
```

```css
div.wrap { border: 5px solid #0a0; }
.wrap div { height: 20px; border: 5px solid #fa0; }
div.new { border: 5px solid #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="first">first</div>
  <div class="asd">asd</div>
  <div class="third">third</div>
</div>
```